# 'Int64Index' object is not callable. What is the most pythonic way of getting the index value when searching for a value in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I wanted to know what was the most pythonic way of getting the index value when searching for a value in a Dataframe.

I've managed it using numpy but I am sure there must be an easier way.

In the example below, I wanted to get the index of the row where column "store_id" has value "66241".

```
In [168]: df.store_id[df.store_id == 66241]
Out[168]:
8    66241.0
Name: store_id, dtype: float64
```

In ouput [168] I can see the index is equal to 8. However, as I wanted to isolate it and save it to a variable, I tried calling it with ".index()"

```
In [169]:df.store_id[df.store_id == 66241].index()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-169-4y*********d>", line 1, in <module>
    data[data.store_id == 66241].index()

TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable
```

When calling it (input [169]) and it gave me a TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable.

So the only way I've managed it, was by using .index and numpy.asarray with int().

```
In [170]: df.store_id[df.store_id == 66241].index
Out[170]: Int64Index([8], dtype='int64')

In [171]: int(np.asarray(df.store_id[df.store_id == 66241].index))
Out[171]: 8
```

Using numpy does the job indeed but it kind of bothers me because I'm sure there is a more pythonic way of doing this.

So the question is: is there a more pythonic way of getting the index? And as I'm still new to python I would love if someone could briefly explain me what the TypeError is about and why numpy gets the job done.

I truely looked everywhere before asking and I apologies if this question was already asked.

Thank you so much for your time,

Best,
Gio.

Comment: We use `()` to run a function, or method, or in general a `callable`.  As `Out[170]` shows the `index` attribute (not a method) is a `pandas` `index` object.  Playing around I thnk `Out[170].item()` will give you `8`.  Or `Out[170][0]` to pick the first item.  Does `pandas` have documentation for this class?

Comment: The docs for the `pandas.Index` class, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html.  Looks like you can do many of same things with it as with a numpy array.  It lists several ways of returning a numpy array.  Under the covers `np.array(...)` works because it uses one of those methods.

Comment: The most pythonic way is to read the documentation - in this case that means reading parts of the `pandas` reference.  There also lots web links explaining what a callable is.

Comment: @hpaulj aight thanks..